# git describe --match does not work on TeamCity

Tags: git, gradle, teamcity, git-tag

In our BitBucket, we have some tags like this:

```
build-0.0.4.152  
0.0.4  
build-0.0.3.151  
build-0.0.3.150  
0.0.3
```

All tags with prefix "*build*" are from intermediate pre-release build where tags without prefix are the versions released in production. I have a gradle method to get the latest production tag from VCS root (so in this case, I expect to get tag `0.0.4`):

```
def getVersionFromTag() {  
   def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()  
  exec {  
   commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--abbrev=0', '--match="[!build]*"'   
   standardOutput = stdout  
  }  
   return stdout.toString().trim()  
}
```

Locally on IntelliJ, the build is able to get the correct tag. However on TeamCity, it shows error in Build log here :

```
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

If I remove the argument `'--match="[!build]*"'` from the command line, in the method above, it WILL WORK but it will get the latest tag (**build-0.0.4.152**, but not what I want **0.0.4**). So I figure that that argument is not available in the git version on TeamCity, but it is available on my own git (2.6.3.windows.1), is that true?

Please correct me if I am wrong and let me know how to get around this. Thank you

Comment: The patter for `--match` is a glob. `git describe --match="[!build]*"` means to find the latest annotated tag whose first character is not `b`, `u`, `i`, `l`, or `d`. Maybe you could use `git describe --abbrev=0 --match="build-*"` to get the latest tag and then parse it to get `0.0.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After remove double-quote, it works

`'--match=[!build]*'`